# Calling BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2 using SAP .NET Connector 3.0 returns "RFC Callback server not available"

Tags: .net, callback, sap-erp, sap-dotnet-connector

I am trying to get a document from SAP DMS using SAP .NET Connector 3.0. I need to get the document and display in ASP.Net.

I am using `BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2` for calling the function. But when the invoke method is called, "RFC callback server not available" error is thrown.

The code I have used is below.

```
...
sap.RfcRepository repo = prd.Repository;
sap.IRfcFunction testBapi = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2");
testBapi.SetValue("DOCUMENTNUMBER", docNumber);
testBapi.SetValue("DOCUMENTPART", docPart);
testBapi.SetValue("DOCUMENTVERSION", docVersion);
testBapi.SetValue("DOCUMENTTYPE", docType);
... 
the document file is created here using BAPI_DOCUMENT_GETDETAIL2
...
testBapi.SetValue("DOCUMENTFILE", struFile);
testBapi.SetValue("GETSTRUCTURE", "1");
testBapi.SetValue("GETHEADER", "X");
testBapi.SetValue("ORIGINALPATH", @"D:\");
testBapi.SetValue("PF_FTP_DEST", "SAPFTPA");

long result = RfcAllowStartProgram("sapftp; saphttp");
testBapi.Invoke(prd);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to download the files by giving file a name somehow in code? in my case it is downloading files in D:\ with same name overwriting existing file.

Comment: This won't work with the official .NET Connector as it don't support ABAP callbacks like RFC_START_PROGRAM. See SAP note: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2297083 I have explained this and how we solved it in more details on this blog: https://dbosoft.eu/en-us/blog/creating-a-sap-dms-library-with-yanco-part-2

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this BAPI and I don't have a system at hand to check it, but I'd assume that somewhere during the execution, the BAPI tries to call "back" to the GUI that's supposed to be at the other end of the session. When it can't find a GUI, it dies. IF you have GUI access and debugging permissions (and knowledge :-)), you could try to find a CALL FUNCTION ... DESTINATION BACK statement on the way.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding one more configuration parameter:

`RfcConfigParameters.UseSAPGui` with value = 1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more information on which RFC server connection is failing?  If you know which connection is the problem, you can ask a SAP Basis/ABAP person to log on to the SAP server & check the RFC destinations in transaction SM59.

EDIT:  Also check the authorizations of the .NET user.

Comment: I checked with the ABAP Person and he said that he is able to access and download the document using SAPGui.

Comment: Hi Sathish, it is unlikely that downloading the document using the SAP GUI has need of the RFC destination.  For interest's sake did the ABAP person use the BAPI to download the document, or the standard DMS transaction?  If using the BAPI, it is possible that the RFC destination would still be accessed.