# start sapgui failed while hosting application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sap-gui, sap-dotnet-connector

I am trying to connect to `SAP` system using `SAP Connector 3.0` to read Documents information (through my `ASP.Net MVC` application). When I run the application through `Visual studio 2012`, `SAP logon screen` launches and my application shows the data after reading from `SAP BAPI's`. But when I deploy the same application using `Visual Studio's` `Publish` option on the same Computer and then run the application I get

```
 Start 'sapgui' failed.
```

Below is the code for reading SAP data in ASP.Net application

```
var documentList =  Global.SAPRepository.CreateFunction("BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2");
documentList.Invoke(Global.SAPDestination);

documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTTYPE", "TPK");
documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTNUMBER", "2000-ABC-T01-TPK");
documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTPART", "000");
documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTVERSION", "A0");

var documentData = documentList.GetTable("DOCUMENTFILES");
documentList.Invoke(Global.SAPDestination);//execute query

var docNo = documentData.GetString("DOCUMENTNUMBER");
var type = documentData.GetString("DOCUMENTTYPE");
var version = documentData.GetString("DOCUMENTVERSION");
```

While here is the code for connecting to SAP Destination.

```
public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
    {
        RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();
        if ("Dev".Equals(destinationName))
        {
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "192.168.x.xx");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "00");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "myuserName");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, myPassword);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "900");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.UseSAPGui, "1");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PeakConnectionsLimit, "10");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.ConnectionIdleTimeout, "600");
        }
        return parms;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `UseSAPGui` configuration parameter to "0". You cannot use the interactive logon dialog (which is a Windows dialog) when running as an ASP.NET application. SAPGui does not open in "unattended mode" - that is, when there will be no user to interact with dialogs.

The other problem, callbacks not supported, is discussed here:
[Calling BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2 using SAP.Net Connector 3.0 returns "RFC Callback server not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047227/calling-bapi-document-checkoutview2-using-sap-net-connector-3-0-returns-rfc-cal)

The solution seems to be to set `UseSAPGui` to 1 to enable the callback, which you cannot do. So this is a dead end. Recommendation is to use an alternative BAPI that is fully RFC-enabled, or write a custom wrapper (in ABAP) that does not involve the callback.

Comment: this results in the message `Callbacks from ABAP are not supported`

Comment: where: on create destination, on connect, on retrieve?

Comment: `Callbacks from ABAP are not supported` comes when calling `documentList.Invoke(Global.SAPDestination);`

Comment: ok this will not be related to the sapgui. I assume when you're starting with Visual Studio, you are running with VS Development Server as the logged on user, while in IIS, you are running as ApplicationPoolIdentity? I would have suspected [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3690535) but as you say it works in the debugger, I'm out of ideas for the moment.

Comment: what I am saying is if `UseSAPGui` config is set to 1 then I get `Start 'sapgui' failed.` but I dont know on which line of code this error comes since this only comes in case of app running thru `IIS` but if i set the `UseSAPGui` to 0 and then run the application, then even in Visual studio debugger I get the error message `Callbacks from ABAP are not supported`

Comment: I see. then I am afraid there is no better news than repeating what this article says: [NCo 3 does not support RFC BAPI calls that do callbacks](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3690535)

Comment: Please see the answer I posted in case you want to see how I solved :)

Answer (score 1):

So basically it turns out that since my application is hosted in `IIS` and  `IIS` is running as a `Windows service` and it does not allow to launch other processes that will interact with Desktop. Since `BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2` tries to launch `SAPGUI` process, therefore it throws error message.

So the solution I implemented is that I wrote a `WCF` service that I hosted in a Managed Windows Console Application like below (simple Windows Console Application in VS 2012).

Service Interface definition goes here

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ViewDocuments();
}
```

Service implementation class goes here

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string ViewDocuments()
    {
        var documentList = Global.SAPRepository.CreateFunction("BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2");
        documentList.Invoke(Global.SAPDestination);

        documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTTYPE", "TPK");
        documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTNUMBER", "2000-Abc-T01-TPK");
        documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTPART", "000");
        documentList.SetValue("DOCUMENTVERSION", "A0");

        var documentData = documentList.GetTable("DOCUMENTFILES");
        documentList.Invoke(Global.SAPDestination);//execute query

        var docNo= documentData.GetString("DOCUMENTNUMBER");
        var type = documentData.GetString("DOCUMENTTYPE");
        var version = documentData.GetString("DOCUMENTVERSION");
        return docNo;
    }
}
```

And the Main method of the Console application is

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8085/hello");

        // Create the ServiceHost.
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), baseAddress))
        {
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHost.
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have added reference to `System.ServiceModel` in the Console Application as well.

Then I consumed this service in my Asp.Net application, every thing worked like a charm!!!

Comment: Hi, can I ask you where you put the configuration UseSapGui = 1 in this service, or if you don't use it how this works if callback are not supported without UseSapGui enabled?